# Linker error with iniparser

Tags: c++, c++11, linker-errors, fedora, ini

I am trying to compile a project from source and receiving several undefined reference linker errors

```
g++  src/Misc/Utils.o src/Misc/Timer.o  ... -o bin/nsnake  -lncurses -liniparser

src/Config/INI.o: In function `INI::load(std::string)':                    
INI.cpp:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `iniparser_load(char const*)'
...
INI.cpp:(.text+0x726): undefined reference to `iniparser_dump_ini(_dictionary_*, _IO_FILE*)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [nsnake] Error 1
```

I have already checked `/lib` and `/usr/lib` and both contain `libiniparser.so.0` and the `libiniparser.so -> libiniparser.so.0` symlink. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: The functions in the library probably have C linkage and their declarations are missing `extern "C"`

Comment: That actually answered my question. :) I checked out a previous commit and for some reason the author had removed a local version of iniparser. After rolling back, I was able to compile just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `extern "C" { #include <iniparser.h> }`
in order for the compiler to link correctly.